# MULE HTTP listener attachment with rest web service

Tags: file, rest, mule, attachment

I am New to MULE ESB I am tryting to handle file attachment with http listener using rest web service.

I am created a simple flow but dont know how to handle attachment in mule to pass rest ful web service .

Any help greatly appreciated!!

:(

Comment: Any one ?? who can help here with MULE ESB

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Given is simple flow waht i am assuming to be work !!

rest web service code ::

```
    package com.one.file;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;

@Path("/upload")

public class RESTMultipleFileUpload {

    private static final String FILE_UPLOAD_PATH = "C:\\Users\\charan\\Documents\\webservice\\";
    //private static final String CANDIDATE_NAME = "candidateName";
    private static final String SUCCESS_RESPONSE = "Successful";
    private static final String FAILED_RESPONSE = "Failed";

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces("text/plain")
    @Path("/multipleFiles")
    public String registerWebService(@Context HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        String responseStatus = SUCCESS_RESPONSE;        
        String candidateName = null;
        System.out.println("first ");
        System.out.println("Two::"+request);
        //checks whether there is a file upload request or not
        if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request))
        {
            final FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
            final ServletFileUpload fileUpload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
            try
            {
                System.out.println("t ");
                /*
                 * parseRequest returns a list of FileItem
                 * but in old (pre-java5) style
                 */
                final List items = fileUpload.parseRequest(request);

                if (items != null)
                {
                    final Iterator iter = items.iterator();
                    while (iter.hasNext())
                    {
                        final FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();
                        final String itemName = item.getName();
                        final String fieldName = item.getFieldName(); 
                        final String fieldValue = item.getString();

                        if (item.isFormField())
                        {
                            candidateName = fieldValue;
                            System.out.println("Field Name: " + fieldName + ", Field Value: " + fieldValue);
                            System.out.println("Candidate Name: " + candidateName);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                final File savedFile = new File(FILE_UPLOAD_PATH + File.separator
                                         + itemName);
                                System.out.println("Saving the file: " + savedFile.getName());
                                item.write(savedFile);                                
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (FileUploadException fue)
            {
                responseStatus = FAILED_RESPONSE;
                fue.printStackTrace();                
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                responseStatus = FAILED_RESPONSE;
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }        

        System.out.println("Returned Response Status: " + responseStatus);

        return responseStatus;
    }


}
```